# Determining Resourceful Routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm looking to create DRY shoulda-style matchers for resourceful routes:

```
it { should resource(:users) }
it { should resource(:articles), only: 'index' }
```

Is there a way to determine whether a series of routes were created via [resourceful routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources_path_names)?

The alternative I've considered is generating the expected routes in an isolated engine for comparison:

```
class RouteTestEngine < Rails::Engine; end

RouteTestEngine.routes.draw do
  resources :users
end

# A *very* rough draft of the assertion that would follow:
expect(Rails.application.routes.named_routes).to include RouteTestEngine.routes.named_routes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you would be testing anything useful here, just verifying that you typed the routes correctly by entering a second time.

The standard routing spec matchers would be better:
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/routing-specs

They allow you to ensure that every route goes where you want it, even the ones generated by `resource`.

Comment: "... just verifying that you typed the routes correctly by entering a second time..." ...and that the route required by specification has been created in the first place. My objective is to make the specs DRY and avoid repeating umpteen spec blocks for each resourceful route. The standard matchers make sense for more "unique" routes (e.g. `/sign-in`).

Comment: I second this answer. Basically you are using Shoulda to test if Rails works, not meaningful.